# Calling a derived class from my driver.cpp

Tags: c++, class, derived

I would be very grateful for some help.  In my computer science class, we're being asked to do something I've never done before, and I don't understand my problem well enough to even know what terms to Google.

We have three files.  lists.h, lists.cpp and driver.cpp

lists.h - this was provided by the professor and CANNOT be altered by me.  It's the base class from which I will derive a new class in...

lists.cpp - Here I implement and doubly-linked list in class DLList.  I've done dll before, but not this way.  So you'll see a lot of code here despite me not being able to test any of it.  Don't worry if my functions are wrong here, I'm simply trying to create a doubly linked list in ...

driver.cpp - this is the file I'll be using to test my functions in class DLList.

So anyway, I compile and get ....

```
g++ -c -g -Wall -std=c++11 driver.cpp
driver.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
driver.cpp:12:5: error: ‘DLList’ was not declared in this scope
     DLList<int> mylist;
     ^
```

I understand the error.  I've seen this before when a function/class/etc is not being seen by main.  In simpler code, it is because it is after main.  But here, I just don't know how to fix it.  Obviously, driver.cpp cannot see my code in lists.cpp.

Here is my code --

the unalterable lists.h

```
template<typename E> class List {
private:
    void operator =(const List&) {}  // Protect assignment
    List(const List&) {}    // Protect copy constructor
public:
    List() {}  // Default constructor
    virtual  ~List() {} // Base destructor

    // Clear contents from the list, freeing memory
    virtual void clear() = 0;

    // Insert an element at the beginning of the list.
    virtual void prepend(const E& item) = 0;

    // Append an element at the end of the list.
    virtual void append(const E& item) = 0;

    // Extra credit: Insert an element at the current location, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if there is no current element
    virtual bool insert(const E& item) = 0;

    // Extra credit: Remove and assign to item the current element, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if there is no current element
    virtual bool remove(E& item) = 0;

    // Set the current position to the first element of the list, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if list was empty
    virtual bool moveToStart() = 0;

    // Set the current position to the last element of the list, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if list was empty
    virtual bool moveToEnd() = 0;

    // Move the current position one step right, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if already at the end
    virtual bool next() = 0;

    // Move the current position one step left, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if already at the beginning
    virtual bool prev() = 0;

    // Return a pointer to the current element (or NULL if none)
    virtual const E* getValue() const = 0;

    // Return total number of active nodes
    virtual int numActive() = 0;

    // Return total number of free nodes
    virtual int numFree() = 0;
};


// Factory function
template<typename E> List<E> *createList();
```

lists.cpp

```
#include "lists.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Doubly linked list link node with freelist support
template <typename E> class Link {
private:
    // required by Lab 4
    static int free; // # of nodes free
    static int active; // # of nodes in use
    static Link<E> *freelist; // Reference to freelist head

    E element; // Value for this node
    Link *next; // Pointer to next node in list
    Link *prev; // Pointer to previous node

public:
    // Constructors
    Link(const E& it, Link *prevp=NULL, Link *nextp=NULL) {
        element = it;
        prev = prevp;
        next = nextp;
    }

    Link(Link *prevp =NULL, Link *nextp =NULL) {
        prev = prevp;
        next = nextp;
    }

    void * operator new(std::size_t) { // Overloaded new operator
        active++; // add to active count

        if (freelist == NULL) { // Create space
            return ::new Link; // ::new means use the standard c++ new operator
        }

        Link<E> *temp = freelist; // Can take from freelist
        freelist = freelist->next;
        free--; // will only subtract if we take from freelist

        return temp; // Return the link
    }

// Overloaded delete operator
    void operator delete(void* ptr) {
        free++;
        active--;
        // eliminate the Link being deleted from the active list
        Link *prev_tmp=((Link<E>*)ptr)->prev;
        Link *next_tmp=((Link<E>*)ptr)->next;
        prev_tmp->next=next_tmp;
        next_tmp->prev=prev_tmp;

        ((Link<E>*)ptr)->next = freelist; // Attach deleted Link to the head of the freelist
        freelist = (Link<E>*)ptr; // Now redefine the freelist to the new head
    }

    E get_data() const {
        return element;
    }

    E set_data(E& it) {
        element=it;
    }

    Link<E> *get_next() const {
        return next;
    }

    Link<E> *get_ptrb() const {
        return prev;
    }

    void set_next(Link<E> *new_next ) {
        next = new_next;
    }

    void set_prev(Link<E> *new_prev) {
        prev = new_prev;
    }

    int get_free() {
        return free;
    }

    int get_active(){
        return active;
    }

};
// The freelist head pointer is actually created here
template <typename E>
Link<E> *Link<E>::freelist = NULL;




template <typename E> class DLList: public List<E> {
private:
    Link<E> *head; // Pointer to list header
    Link<E> *tail; // Pointer to last element
    Link<E> *curr; // Access to current element

    void operator =(const DLList&) {}  // Protect assignment
    DLList(const DLList&) {}    // Protect copy constructor

public:
    // Default constructor
    DLList() {
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }

    // Base destructor
    ~DLList() {
        //delete
    }

    // Clear contents from the DLList, freeing memory
    void clear() = 0;

    // Insert an element at the beginning of the DLList.
    void prepend(const E& item) {
        Link<E> *newLink = new Link<E>(item);

        if (head==NULL) {
            head=newLink;
            tail=newLink;
            curr=newLink;
        }
        else {
            newLink->set_next(head);
            head=newLink;
            curr=newLink;
        }

    }

    // Append an element at the end of the DLList.
    void append(const E& item) {
        Link<E> *newLink = new Link<E>(item);

        if (head==NULL) {
            head=newLink;
            tail=newLink;
            curr=newLink;
        }
        else {
            tail->set_next(newLink);
            tail=newLink;
            curr=newLink;
        }

    }

    void print_list() {
        if (head==NULL) {
            cout << "EMPTY LIST" << endl;
        }
        else {
            Link<E> *temp_ptr = head;
            int index=0;
            while(temp_ptr) {
                cout << "Link " << index++ << ": " << temp_ptr->get_data()  << endl;
                temp_ptr = temp_ptr->get_next();
            }
        }
    }

    // Extra credit: Insert an element at the current location, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if there is no current element
    bool insert(const E& item) {
        if (curr==NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            Link<E> *newLink = new Link<E>(item);
            Link<E> *prev_ptr=curr->get_prev;
            Link<E> *next_ptr=curr->get_next();

            prev_ptr->set_next(curr);
            curr->set_prev(prev_ptr);

            next_ptr->set_prev(curr);
            curr->set_next(next_ptr);

            return true;
        }
    }

    // Extra credit: Remove and assign to item the current element, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if there is no current element
    bool remove(E& item) {
        if (curr==NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            curr->set_data(item);
        }
    }

    // Set the current position to the first element of the DLList, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if DLList was empty
    bool moveToStart() {
        if (head==NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            curr=head;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Set the current position to the last element of the DLList, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if DLList was empty
    bool moveToEnd() {
        if (head==NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            curr=tail;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Move the current position one step right, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if already at the end
    bool next() {
        if (curr==tail) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            curr=curr->get_next();
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Move the current position one step left, if possible;
    // return true if successful, false if already at the beginning
    bool prev() {
        if (curr==head) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            curr=curr->get_prev();
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Return a pointer to the current element (or NULL if none)
    const E* getValue() {
        if (curr==NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        else {
            curr->get_data();
        }
    }


    // ******** MIGHT HAVE TO GET THIS DATA FROM MULTIPLE SOURCES IF THE PTR IS NULL!!
    // BUG !
    // Return total number of active nodes
    int numActive() {
        return curr->get_active();
    }

    // ******** MIGHT HAVE TO GET THIS DATA FROM MULTIPLE SOURCES IF THE PTR IS NULL!!
    // BUG !
    // Return total number of free nodes
    int numFree() {
        return curr->get_free();
    }
};

// Explicit instantiation
template List<int> *createList();
```

driver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lists.h"
using namespace std;

void uppercaseify(string& mystr) {
    for (auto& c: mystr)
        c = toupper(c);
}

int main() {
    createList<int>();
    DLList<int> mylist;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you actually _required_ to put your code in `list.cpp`? That's not how things should be set up.

Comment: Your prof mixes up a container class with iterator functions (moveToStart, moveToEnd, prev, next), that's very bad design!

Comment: Yes, I have to put all the functional code in lists.cpp, and all the testing code in driver.cpp. :/

Comment: It actually makes sense, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not supposed to explicitly instantiate your DLList class in main(). This can't work because you don't have the declaration of it available in "driver.cpp".

What you should do instead is implement the factory function in "list.cpp" to return a dynamically allocated instance of your DLList:

```
template<> List<int> *createList() { return new DLList<int>; }
```

So the call to `createList<int>()` in "driver.cpp" will then create an instance of your DLList which you can test through the interface of List:

```
int main() {
    // Create a DLList through factory function.
    List<int>* list = createList<int>();

    // Use the DLList through the List interface.
    list->append( ... );    

    // Finished with using list, free the memory
    delete list; list = nullptr;

    // Not necessary - we have created the DLList through factory function!
    // DLList<int> mylist;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually I would use a `std::unique_ptr<List<int>>` instead of the raw pointer and get rid of the explicit `delete` but I don't know if you are 'allowed' to use that. So I kept it to the basics ;-)

Comment: Ah, almost!  Least amount of errors I've received yet from the compiler!  I'm still getting this: lists.cpp:283:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 template List<int> *createList() { return new DLList<int>; }
                                  ^
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: Add `<>` after `template` and it works. This syntax is called template specialization.

Comment: Sorry, I feel bad.  But I still cannot get it to work

Comment: `lists.cpp: In function ‘List<E>* createList() [with E = int]’:
lists.cpp:283:49: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘DLList<int>’
 template<> List<int> *createList() { return new DLList<int>; }
                                                 ^
lists.cpp:103:29: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘DLList<int>’:
 template <typename E> class DLList: public List<E> {
                             ^
`

Comment: You didn't implement all abstract methods of List<E>, e. g. `void clear() = 0;` so the compiler considers your class still abstract and can't instantiate it.

Comment: You are also missing the `const` after getValue() so the compiler won't use your method to override the method of the base class. Generally consider adding the `override` keyword to all the methods you override, so the compiler can point out such errors easier. E. g. `const E* getValue() const override {`

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I have to give it up for the night but I will get on it tomorrow.  I deeply, deeply appreciate your help.  I'll keep you updated tomorrow!

Comment: I just barely got back to this about an hour ago, but it's compiling!  I have the basics working!  Many many thank yous!

Answer (score 0):

Well you're right, the error is there because there is no DLList type declared in your driver file. The easiest option to fix it would be to include your list.cpp file into your driver file

```
#include "list.cpp"
```

Generally when you're working with a .h and a .cpp file that have the same name they should refer to the same class. So if you were writing this example outside of a class exercise you would probably name your list.cpp file DLList.h (note that template classes should be in a .h file).

Comment: The error is to try to instantiate DLList<int> explicitly instead of only through the factory function createList. With this removed, there is no need to include "list.cpp" at all.